# Javascript iframe messaging event origin

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on a wordpress page which has an iframe and receives messages from https://host.xyz.co:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if(event.origin == "https://host.xyz.com") {
        if(typeof event.data.message.iframeHeight != 'undefined'){
        jQuery('#fc-iframe').height(event.data.message.iframeHeight)
    }
}
```

This worked 100% as expected for the past 6 months, then yesterday it broke.  The page receives the message, the event.origin does in fact == "https://host.xyz.com", however, if I add a console.log(event.origin == "https://host.xyz.com") it returns false.  If I assign the event origin to a variable, and then in the console I enter event.origin == "https://host.xyz.com" it returns true.

I have verified that the event origin is in fact a string, I have verified that it does not have any weird characters using JSON.stringify, the strings match, yet it returns false as though they do not.

I feel like there is something simple I am missing, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.  This is a page on a wordpress install, not sure if any updates maybe affected this?

For now, I am removing the check, but I would love to figure out why this is happening.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: slice the event.origin and "https://host.xyz.com" ,then do the comparision,find which positioin the difference happens

Comment: slicing the event.origin returns https://host.xyz.com
slicing "https://host.xyz.com" returns //host.xyz.com

Comment: I see what is happening, wordpress is stripping the "https://" from the javascript.  Thanks for the help xianshenglu.